# How can I solve these memory leak in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I checked my application's memory leaking problem and these memory leaks are found. 
How can I solve these memory leak?

I used `Leaks` tool in `Instruments`. Here are the screenshots

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAkyL.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iTpH.png)

Comment: @YunCHEN Thank u for answering. But I don't know which one is wrong. There are no black code. I added image in my question, please check it.

Comment: I added a screenshot with answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the Call Tree, select the options indicated in screenshot, then double click the code line.

[image]